# Disable NX bit in Linux PERMANENTLY

Tags: linux, 64-bit

I have Debian-based Linux (Astra Linux, 64-bit) and I need to disable NX bit (it's Intel-based, so maybe I should say *XD bit*) completely, as my laptop has some defect that won't allow it to work normally with this function enabled.

I've managed to found several instructions regarding noexec=off, however, all of them refers to disabling it while booting, which means NX bit always comes back after reboot.

How to **get rid of it completely** and is there any short simple command to check if it's active after booting to desktop?

Comment: `all of them refers to disabling it while booting, which means NX bit always comes back after reboot.` You just need to edit your boot/grub conf (*instead of* e.g., pressing `e` on the grub menu to edit the line) so that it boots with `noexec=off` *automatically* every time?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make it boot with noexec=off automatically every time. There is Grub editor in this system, but I am not sure what to edit where, maybe there is a way to edit it through console? And I guess noexec32=off is also needed, just in case.

Comment: Well often you just edit `/etc/default/grub` and add it to either of [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440962) and run `grub[2]-mkconfig` or `update-grub` (whichever suits your distro).

Comment: Ok, I will try it, thanks.

Comment: It should look like GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noexec=off noexec32=off" ?

Comment: I suppose. Try it and see. Make sure you regen the real conf as instructed above. Then you can reboot and check whether they are there automatically with `e`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Checking via terminal it confirms the XD bit is now disabled.